# What is the original source of "fiber" in mathematics?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, education, math-history

Maybe this question is not relevant to mathematics, but I am very curious. I am studying Abstract Algebra these days.

I learn that the word *fibre* with definition: $f^{-1}({y}) = \{x \in X | f(x) = y\}$ for $\forall y \in Y$, where $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a map.

And the definition of **normal**  *fiber* in Wikipedia states:

> **Fiber** or **fibre** (from the Latin fibra) is a natural or synthetic substance that is significantly longer than it is wide. Fibers are often used in the manufacture of other materials.

Does *fiber* in mathematics have any relationship with the normal defintion? Or are they somewhat alike? Why do they define the *inverse image* with *fibre*?

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Generally speaking, mathematical terminology bears only a tenuous, if often suggestive, relationship to the ordinary uses of the same words. Be wary of drawing too close a link. Nevertheless it is often interesting to see the primary source where a particular term caught on. In this case, see http://jeff560.tripod.com/f.html

Comment: @symplectomorphic I am just curious. Thank you very much!

Comment: +1 for "source of fiber" (even though this makes me think that this question is just for the pun).

Comment: May I add that this usage of the word "fiber" is somewhat stretched. More universally, $f^{-1}(y)$ is called a *pre-image*. Surely the author you are reading has a background in geometry.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

My guess would be that it came from a geometric picture like the following one (picture taken from Wikipedia):

[image]

What you're looking at is an example of a vector bundle (specifically, a line bundle) which is a particular type of fiber bundle. The idea is that if we let $M$ be the Mobius strip and $S^1$ the black line (really a circle) pictured, then there is a map $M\to S^1$ by projecting down vertically onto $S^1$.

The fiber over a point $P$ of $S^1$, say we take $P$ lying on the portion highlighted red, is then just the vertical line on $M$ running perpendicular to the red line, crossing through $P$. In this sense it is some "thin strand" lying over our point, which intuitively seems to match the definition of "fiber" you quoted.

Answer (score 13):

I would guess that fiber really comes from the geometric/topological definition of a [fiber bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_bundle) which has been transported into algebraic language.

In particular, used in the sense that it is a "thread" or "string" to build larger things out of (fiber of a textile, or fiber muscle.)

From this, it makes sense, since $X= \bigcup_{y \in Y} f^{-1}(\{y\})$, so $X$ can be built out of the preimages (or) for $Y$. This is especially the case if you keep the first isomorphism theorem in mind:

$$X/ \ker \phi \cong Y$$

So the equivalence classes $[x]:=x+ \ker\phi$ are thought of as being your space built up from the "thinner" pieces that can be identified with preimages of $y \in Y$.

---

If you care for a more general approach (*this is certainly not where it comes from*), there is the categorical notion of the [fibered product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_(category_theory)) which is essentially a ``pullback diagram."

In the case where $f:A \to B$ is some morphism and $i:B^{\prime}\hookrightarrow B$ is just inclusion, then the pullback (or fibered product) of $f$ and $i$, is just the preimage of $B^{\prime}$ along with inclusion into $A$. In particular, if $B^{\prime}$ is a single element, then it is the preimage, (or fiber) at a point $b \in B$.

Answer (score 6):

Without having a source, it appears plausible to me that the term fiber comes from *projection-like* maps $f:X\to Y$ where $X$ can be thought of as looking somehow like $Y\times[0,1]$ (a cylinder over $Y$, or more generally, a fiber bundle).

Consider this picture:

[image]

The preimage $f^{-1}(y)$ is a "line over $y$". If you look at *many* such points $y$ and their preimages simultaneously, then you can get the impression that $X$ is a thick bundle of these lines, or *fibers*, tightly packed together (like a rope).

Answer (score 6):

From http://jeff560.tripod.com/f.html:

> **FIBER**, **FIBER BUNDLE**, and **FIBER SPACE**. According to J. Dieudonné *A
>   History of Algebraic and Differential Topology* 1900-1960 p. 387, the
>   terms “fiber” (German “Faser”) and “fiber space” (“gefaserter Raum”)
>   probably first appeared in Herbert Seifert “Topologie
>   dreidimensionaler gefaserter, Räume,” *Acta Mathematica*, 60, (1932),
>   147-238. However, Dieudonné adds that Seifert’s definitions “are
>   limited to a very special case and his point of view is rather
>   different from the modern concepts.” The modern concepts appear in the
>   1940s principally in the work of Hassler Whitney. Whitney defines a
>   fibre-bundle in “On the Theory of Sphere-Bundles”, *Proceedings of the
>   National Academy of Sciences of the United States of America*, 26, No.
>   2 (Feb. 15, 1940), p. 148. Within a few years the related terms
>   *bundle*, *fibre* and *fibre space* appeared: see N. Steenrod *The Topology
>   of Fibre Bundles* (1951). In recent years the spelling *fiber* has become
>   usual, conforming to common US usage.

Wikipedia adds that Seifert's definition didn't include the base space, and that Whitney first considered only spherical fibers.

Interestingly, the Hopf Fibration was named *after* Heinz Hopf.  His original work, *Über die Abbildungen der dreidimensionalen Sphäre
auf die Kugelfäche* from 1931 describes a surjective map $S^3\to S^2$ that is not nullhomotopic.  I cannot find a reference, but I would not be surprised if Whitney put it into the language of $S^1$ bundles.

In modern terminology, a fiber bundle is a map $p:E\to B$ with some additional properties, and each fiber is the inverse image of a point in the base space $B$.  It is not too big of a leap to say that the fibers of an arbitrary map are the inverse images of points.

For groups, a map $p:G\to H$ gives a decomposition of $G$ into fibers, each of which is a coset of $\ker p$.  If $G,H$ are topological groups, this indeed decomposes $G$ as a fiber space.

Another example is $p:SL(2,\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}^2-\{(0,0)\}$ defined by $p(A)=Ae_1$.  The fibers of this map are cosets of the stabilizer of the vector $e_1$, and one can check these fibers are 1-dimensional.  This decomposes $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ as a fiber space, and furthermore shows that the group is homeomorphic to a solid torus.